# get named placeholders from prepared mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, query-string

Given a prepared MySQL statement in PHP, how can I select the named placeholders from it?

For example, if the query I'm preparing is

```
SELECT name, colour FROM fruit WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour
```

or

```
INSERT INTO people (name, position, admin_level) VALUES (:name, :pos, 0)
```

then I would like as output `array(":calories",":colour")` or `array(":name",":pos")`.

This feature seems not listed on the PHP site. Is there any way to get the named placeholders from the prepared statement?

Comment: It is not useful to autofill anything from the $_POST array, unless you are a hacker. This would be **INCREDIBLY DANGEROUS** built to catch the noob and help them develop sites that were **SO EASILY HACKABLE**

Comment: That's not the point. The current code also fills them with stuff from $_POST, that's what forms do and it's perfectly possible to do this in a secure way. All that I ask is how to select these tokens from the query.

Comment: Ok I saw the silly bit and it blinded me to the actual question.

Comment: Ok, I've removed that part then, it was merely intended to illustrate a usecase for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use some sort of string manipulation to do what I think you are asking. I know of no standard mechanism that will do this. So something like this :-

```
$q = 'SELECT name, colour FROM fruit WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';

$res = preg_match_all('/:[a-z]+/',$q, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Would generate something like this :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => :calories
        [1] => :colour
    )
)
```

Beware, I am no regex expert, so this would need a bit of testing to make sure it didn't break on some complete query.

**After Some Research I found**

Alternatively, if you want this information after you have completed the

```
->prepare()
->bindParams()
->execute()
```

and generated a statement handle, you could use :-

```
$stmt->debugDumpParams()
```

[Link to the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php), radical idea I know, now we have both learnt something because I had never seen this before either.

Comment: Yes, this way it can be fetched from the query, but I would hope/assume there is also a way to directly fetch it from the prepared statement. How does the database even prepare the statement if it would be unaware of which placeholders need to be assigned?

Comment: The prepare goes on on the database server not in the php extension and is linked to your connection. To get it back would require some sort of request to the database server to return it, which makes no sence and therefore does not exist.

Comment: Why does it make no sense? The PHP syntax is something like `$stmt = $db->prepare($query); $stmt->execute($params);` where an actual object `$stmt` is returned by the DB between preparation and execution. So why would it not make sense to have a `$stmt->listofplaceholders()` method on that?

Comment: Oh you want this information after you have created a statement handle. I thought you wanted it before the bindParam() phase. See answer for extra info.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a debug function, which prints the information directly to the screen rather than allowing me to manipulate it easier. So I guess that will mean a no to my original question. Besides, shouldn't this information technically already be available after the `prepare($query)` phase and before the `execute($params)` phase? The prepared query (right after the `prepare($query)` command) should already have the slots for the parameters to bind figured out, right?

Comment: But like I said before, the `prepare()` statement sends the raw text of your query complete with `:var` or `?` directly to the server and the server itself does the preparation and stores the result. The bindParams then send a set of values to be bound to the prepared query (on the server). Nothing is maintained locally to PHP of the PDO extension. So who would want to add extra round trips to there database server to get this data, when it could be busily doing useful work instead.

Comment: That's true. I thought this data would be accessible in the `$stmt` object without another round trip to the database, but I guess not then. Thanks for the answers!